# How to find architectural antipatterns / bad smells?

Tags: architecture, software

I'm looking for architectural anti patterns / bad smells, and just wondering how to do this? Is there some sort of detection strategy, some way to find potential places or object-oriented metrics, suitable for finding these problems? This approach should be applicable on extracted / recovered architecture (from source codes) .

A catalog of these bad smells could be fined on :

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.184.661&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Imagine if you asked this question about *actual architecture*. Here, I have a building that is almost impossible to get into or out of, with many tiny high windows. Good architecture or bad architecture? It kind of depends on whether its a jail, an elementary school, a hospital, a giraffe paddock, a church, a software company office...  Architecture is good or bad depending on how well it fulfills the intended use of the space.

Comment: @EricLippert Considering the dominance of cargo-cult design techniques ("principles" instead of logical design), a lack of "principle" adherence might be labeled "smells". People are searching for ways to evaluate software without any understanding of the specific needs of the software. Of course it is all a bit nuts.

Answer (score 1):

The architecture of a system describes the *high-level design decisions and values* that guide the development of that system. There are a couple of architecture-level patterns that avoid specific problems, but there isn't a “correct” or “best” architecture. There also isn't a single architecture for each system. Architecture can describe how the components of a system interact, how the system is deployed, how security is maintained, how technologies are chosen, ….

Because architecture is about *decisions*, it is not generally possible to reverse-engineer these decisions. You might notice some architecture patterns (e.g. a microservice architecture, or a MVVM architecture), but that is not the same as understanding why this architecture was chosen for that problem domain.

Whether an architecture is suitable depends a lot on the purpose and context of that system. E.g. designing a system around a central message bus can make a lot of sense to integrate business data sources, but it is probably a pointless architecture for a spreadsheet application like MS Excel. I don't think it's sensible to express this necessary context as as part of some “metric”. Instead, we have to ask ourselves:

*Given this architecture for this problem:*

- *How does the architecture help solving that problem?*
- *How does it make a solution more difficult?*

Unfortunately, this requires *experience*. Until you've experienced various shortcomings of an architecture, you probably wouldn't think of these problems. Those are *unknown unknowns*. But once we know how not to solve this problem, we can evaluate an architecture and say: “In my experience, this architecture has difficulties with $feature”, where the feature in question may be a quality like scalability, maintainability, reliability, separation of concerns, or anything else.

Comment: Dear @amon, your answer is based on common sense of architecture , and it's OK. But the point of my question is detection of architectural problems just like object-oriented design... you know we have architectural problems like "Connector Envy", "Scattered Functionality", "Ambiguous Interfaces" or "Extraneous Adjacent Connector". A catalogue of this architecture smells exist on : http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.184.661&rep=rep1&type=pdf .I love to hear the voice of experience :)

Comment: @HamidMousaviNasab In a different version of that paper, the authors say: “*Defining architectural smells in terms of standard architectural building blocks makes it possible to audit documented or recovered architecture for possible smells without needing to understand the history of a software system.*” Are you asking about that? The authors seem to be proposing various architecture antipatterns for possible problems, so that it becomes easier to notice them in an existing design.

Comment: My Friend @amon. In reply to your question, Yes, exactly. But the authors doesn't mention any way to find these smells easily.. you know, I'm working on paper and i'm in need to find most (if not all of) these architectural smells. How should it be done ? Can i use cyclomatic complexity ? Or some sort of detection strategy based on object-oriented metrics, is the way i'm looking for ?